# Counting the number of duplicate key values in a map

Tags: java, groovy

I have a map I have constructed. It iterates through a huge WAPI reply in XML format and creates this map. For each name I want to grab the name, then the total number of matching carrierpairs, then the cheapest price for that name.

So based on below the result would be:

```
 AACATDOM: [AA/AA: 3, UA/AA: 1] 390.99
 11PUB2: [ UA/AA: 1, AS/AS: 4] 486.99

 myMap = [[name:AACATDOM, cost:390.99, carrierpair:AA/AA], [name:AACATDOM, cost:390.99, carrierpair:AA/AA], [name:AACATDOM, cost:395.99, carrierpair:UA/AA], [name:AACATDOM, cost:393.99, carrierpair:AA/AA], [name:AACATDOM, cost:393.99, carrierpair:AA/AA], [name:11PUB2, cost:486.99, carrierpair:UA/AA], [name:11PUB2, cost:486.99, carrierpair:UA/AA], [name:11PUB2, cost:892.99, carrierpair:AS/AS], [name:11PUB2, cost:892.99, carrierpair:AS/AS], [name:11PUB2, cost:892.99, carrierpair:AS/AS], [name:11PUB2, cost:892.99, carrierpair:AS/AS]]
```

A bit stumped on this one! Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: According to what you have shown `myMap` is not represented as a map but as a list (or an array). Is that right?

Comment: Yes that's correct, sorry.

Comment: Sorry I should have commented this too in my previous comment... but What's is the format of this ouput: `AACATDOM: [AA/AA: 3, UA/AA: 1] 390.99
 11PUB2: [ UA/AA: 1, AS/AS: 4] 486.99`? I mean, it could be a `Map` of `Map`s, but it's not clear to me.

Comment: name: [carrierpair: count, 2nd carrier pair: count] cheapest cost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be an approach using Groovy.

```
def list = [
    [name:'AACATDOM', cost:390.99, carrierpair:'AA/AA'],
    [name:'AACATDOM', cost:390.99, carrierpair:'AA/AA'],
    [name:'AACATDOM', cost:395.99, carrierpair:'UA/AA'],
    [name:'AACATDOM', cost:393.99, carrierpair:'AA/AA'],
    [name:'AACATDOM', cost:393.99, carrierpair:'AA/AA'],
    [name:'11PUB2', cost:486.99, carrierpair:'UA/AA'],
    [name:'11PUB2', cost:486.99, carrierpair:'UA/AA'],
    [name:'11PUB2', cost:892.99, carrierpair:'AS/AS'],
    [name:'11PUB2', cost:892.99, carrierpair:'AS/AS'],
    [name:'11PUB2', cost:892.99, carrierpair:'AS/AS'],
    [name:'11PUB2', cost:892.99, carrierpair:'AS/AS']
]

list.groupBy ({ it.name }, { it.carrierpair }).collectEntries { key, value ->
  [ key, value.collectEntries { k, v -> [ k, v.size() ] } ]
}.collectEntries { key, value ->
  [ key, value << [ minCost: list.findResults { it.name == key ? it.cost : null }.min() ] ]
}

// results:
// [AACATDOM:[AA/AA:4, UA/AA:1, minCost:390.99], 11PUB2:[UA/AA:2, AS/AS:4, minCost:486.99]]
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! I will attempt tomorrow and report back!

Comment: Or `list.groupBy({ it.name }, { it.carrierpair }).collectEntries { k, v -> [k, v.collectEntries { k2, v2 -> [k2, v2.size()] } + [minCost: v.values().cost.flatten().min()] ] }` (just for fun)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Map use [Bag](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/Bag.html) collection which save count by calling [getCount](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/Bag.html#getCount-java.lang.Object-)

> Defines a collection that counts the number of times an object appears in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can build such as map using `Collectors.groupingBy(...)` which produces a data structure like

```
Map<String, List<Value>> map = listOfValues.stream()
                                           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(v -> v.getName());
```

Where the List contains all the values for the same key.

Answer (score 0):

@Sulteric
Let's assume that your data can be described as

```
public class Data  {
    private String name;
    private List<Map<String, Integer>> pairs;
    private Double cost; 
// getters and setters
    public int getPairsCount () {
        return pairs.size();
    }
```

And you will group your processing result in class

```
public class ProcessedData {
    private int pairsCount;
    private Double cheapestCost;    

    public ProcessedData (int pairsCount,Double cheapestCost ) {
        this.pairsCount = pairsCount;
        this.cheapestCost = cheapestCost;
    }
// getters and setters
```

You can do something like:

```
    List<Data> data = new ArrayList<>();
    // Fill the data

    // Find the lowest cost for every name
    Map<String, Double> minByName = data.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Data::getName, Collectors.minBy(Data::getCost)));
    // Counts the pairs for every name and unites this data with min cost
    Map<String, ProcessedData> result = data.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Data::getName, new ProcessedData(Collectors.summingInt(Data::getPairsCount), minByName.get(Data::getName))));   
    // Proceed with result
```